# Validation vs verification in mechanical engineering

Tags: mechanical-engineering, product-testing, project-management

I'm confused about what the difference between Validation and verification is in a mechanical engineering context please?

Also, where in the engineering life cycle/design process are these steps?

What I think they are:
Validation: where you test a product/design to see if it performs as intended
Verification: test a system to prove that it meets all its specified requirements

I looked on this site for an answer, but I don’t feel like they’ve helped my confusion

Comment: I've heard of *design verification*, which would be a methodical process ensure a design, when built to spec, meets requirements, and ideally also that FMEA is addressed. *Validation* and *Qualification* (which we actually do where I am unlike design verification), refer to both processes and tools. Validation means the process, if carried out correctly, produces the required result. Qualification means some aspect of the tool does either what's claimed or what you need it to do. Recommended search term: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=quality+systems+qualification+validation+verification&ia=web

Comment: The terms have a truly specific meaning only within formal standards applicable to quality systems (eg ISO 9001, ISO 13485, GLP GMP etc), and / or coinciding with regulatory requirements of one's industry. But it's a common situation nowadays